# How to hide this extension popup in Edge?

Tags: google-chrome-extensions, chromium, microsoft-edge

Every time I navigate to [chrome web store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redirector/ocgpenflpmgnfapjedencafcfakcekcd/related?hl=en), this pops up. How do I hide this?

[image]

Comment: You have installed the Microsoft Chromium Edge, currently in beta-test. This isn't the final version, so things may change, but try to enable "Allow extensions from other stores".

Comment: Or just block the popup with any ad blocker (e.g. Ublock) or script blocker (e.g. NoScript).

Comment: @Biswapriyo The webstore cannot be scripted by extensions,